# Improving SUMPRODUCT statement on multiple criteria to return

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count all individual instance of a specific aspect having records raised against it that has multiple criteria:

So the unique value would be found in B:B range. The current existing formula is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(DATA!D:D,F9,DATA{"01","09","B01","E-01","N-01","RB01","S01","ZX01","ZX02","ZX03"}))
```

I am wanting to check that IF multiple instances of the same identifier (which will be in DATA!B:B) it is only included once. Atm this check does not exist and so it does that above spot on, but includes and sums the multiple instances (however that might be) when regardless of how many instances I only wanted counted once if the same "identifier"?

Hope that makes sense. New to forums (

Answer (score 0):

Enter this as an array formula (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--(MATCH({"01","09","B01","E-01","N-01","RB01","S01","ZX01","ZX02","ZX03"}&F9,B:B&D:D,0)>0),0))
```